# TextMate find dialog not working

Tags: textmate

So my problem is exactly what it says in the Subject: the find/replace dialog in TextMate is not working anymore.

By that I mean that first off, I have to hit <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> twice to make it even appear.
Then it does not remember any of my settings like "Wrap around" or "Ignore case". But the worst thing is, that it does not give any results on pressing "Next", "Previous" or "Replace" (or any other available button whatsoever).

I already thought it might be a permission problem with some configuration file as it keeps losing my set preferences, but the permissions on the App and both `Application Support`-folders (systemwide and user-specific) seem to be just fine, as is my_username:admin.

Has anyone got an idea how I could adress this issue?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using this as a different user? If that works fine, you may have a corrupted plist file.

If you don't have too many custom settings, try reinstalling TextMate. It is important that you remove the corresponding plist file from ~/Library/Preferences/ before reinstalling.

Answer (score 1):

I would temporarily move ~/Library/Application Support/TextMate aside, as well as ~/Library/Preferences. This will likely establish if it's a setting.

I suspect you have added a bundle which is adversely affecting it.

Answer (score 0):

Were you using Textmate 1.5 or the 2.0 alpha?
In case of the latter, bear in mind that being an alpha, sometimes some things break.

Also, it might sound silly, are you sure you didn't select `Regular Expression` as an option? Sometimes I forget it activated and search doesn't seem to work, only work correctly once I realize that I need to disable it.